# Counterexample for graph isomorphism using eigenvalue multiplicity (connected graphs)

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

Two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ that are cospectral (eigenvalue multisets from their adjacency matrices are the same), do not have to be isomorphic. The pair of cospectral graphs that serve as the [smallest counterexample](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CospectralGraphs.html) to isomorphism are the disjoint graph union of $C_4 \cup K_1$ and the star graph $S_5$.

What is the smallest counterexample known when we require that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are connected?

Comment: [Here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021%2Fci00018a033)'s a counterexample with $8$ vertices.

Comment: @joriki I saw that one after I posted the question, is it known to be the smallest for all connected graphs or just polyhedral ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Harary, King, Mowshowitz, Read, Cospectral graphs and digraphs, Bull London Math Soc 3 (1971) 321-328, give an example of two connected, cospectral, nonisomorphic graphs on 6 vertices, and claim, on the basis of exhaustive search, that it's the smallest.

EDIT: Here's the example. Let the vertices be $A,B,C,D,E,F$. For one graph, join $A$ to each of the other vertices, then join $BC$ and $DE$. For the other, draw a path $ABCDE$, then join $F$ to $B,C,D$.

Comment: I checked this result (here's [the code](https://gist.github.com/1766433)). This is the only example on $6$ vertices, and indeed the smallest. The characteristic polynomial is

$$x^6-7x^4-4x^3+7x^2+4x-1=(x+1)^2(x-1)(x^3-x^2-5x+1)\;.$$

On $7$ vertices there are 31 characteristic polynomials associated with more than one connected graph; only one is connected with three graphs,

$$-x^7+11x^5+10x^4-16x^3-16x^2=-x^2(x+1)(x+2)(x^3-3x^2-4x+8)\;;$$

the edges are

A-B A-C A-D A-E C-E D-E A-F C-F D-F A-G B-G;

A-C B-C B-D A-E B-E C-E D-E B-F C-F D-F A-G;

A-B A-C B-C A-E B-E C-E D-E C-F D-F A-G B-G.

Comment: Ok so how about using the Eigen values and degree sequence together? in fact for speed purposes you would do the degree sequence first. There has to be a way to prove/disprove that if both those qualities are the same then the graphs are isomorphic.

Comment: @Rob, I'm sure there are nonisomorphic graphs that have the same degree sequence and the same eigenvalues. No one has ever found a finite list of invariants to characterize graph isomorphism, and no one expects to. Have you read the Harary et al. paper?

Comment: No I have not, but I will go look it up. I am an amateur at best :). I am about to dive into the recorded lectures discussed in this article https://www.sciencenews.org/article/new-algorithm-cracks-graph-problem