# Graph theory (Chromatic Polynomial)

Tags: graph-theory

What is chromatic polynomial of tree?

What is chromatic polynomial of complete graph with n vertices?

Sketch two different (i.e, nonisomorphic) graphs that have the same chromatic polynomial.

Comment: Maybe this [Counterexample for graph isomorphism using eigenvalue multiplicity](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/106821/19341) helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chromatic polynomial is a polynomial of a graph  which counts the number of distinct ways to color G  with 't' or fewer colors. It counts the number of proper vertex coloring of G.
for details you may refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial.