# Does Weisfeiler-Lehman test distinguishes graphs with simple spectrum of Laplacian?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected, undirected graph. Define graph Laplacian as
$$L_{G} = D^{-1}(D - A) = I - D^{-1}A,$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of degrees and $A$ is an adjacency matrix.

**Question:** Let $G, H$ be two connected non-isomorphic graphs such that $L_{G}$ and $L_{H}$ have simple spectrum (all eigenvalues have multiplicity $1$). Is it true that Weisfeiler-Lehman test (1-WL test) will distinguish $G$ and $H$? I.e.
$$WL(G) \neq WL(H) ?$$

I found that there exist non-isomorphic cospectral graphs with simple spectrum (e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3227759/cospectral-graphs-that-are-non-isomorphic-and-that-only-have-simple-eigenvalues)), but it seems that WL test distinguishes them easily.

Note that my $L_{G}$ and symmetrically normalized Laplacian $L_{sym} = I - D^{-1/2}A D^{-1/2}$ have the same spectrum, if it helps in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two graphs below appear to be a counterexample. (Their Graph6 codes are `M{O_o_H@?G?R?S?I_` and `M{O_o_G@OG?T?Q?K_`.)

[image: two cospectral cubic 14-vertex graphs]

For both graphs, the eigenvalues of $I - D^{-1}A$ are approximately
$$
\{0.,0.258501,0.357451,0.513408,0.609971,0.793989,0.941916,1.14507,1.22963,1.27731,1.53934,1.68564,1.82071,1.82706\}
$$
which are all distinct. We can't distinguish them by eigenvalues, and (as far as I can tell) the Weisfeiler-Lehman just looks at them, shrugs, and gives up, since they are both regular: at each stage of the test, all vertices with have identical labels.

Comment: I double-checked, and you're right. Quite curious because I thought that regularity implies some form of multiplicities in the spectrum.

Comment: In practice, all it guarantees us is an eigenvalue of $0$ (which will not be repeated in connected graphs). Out of the $509$ cubic graphs on $14$ vertices that I checked for this question, $316$ had no repeated eigenvalues. (On the other extreme is what turned out to be the [Heawood graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_graph), with only $4$ distinct eigenvalues.)