# Non-isomorphic co-spectral graphs with distinct eigenvalues

Tags: combinatorics, spectral-graph-theory

There is a polynomial time algorithm by Leighton and Miller for deciding whether cospectral graphs with eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$ are isomorphic.

However, are there any known cospectral graphs with eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$ that are not isomorphic?

The only non-isomorphic graphs with same spectrum of known multiplicities I can think of are strongly regular graphs, and since these have exactly $3$ eigenvalues, they do not provide an answer to the above.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3227784/274

Comment: (I got that by googling «cospectral graphs without multiplicities» and looking at the first result!)